# How to use Nsolve to tackle a Bessel-related function?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I tried to get the result of the value of ncoeff as the function of wl,codes was pasted blow as well as the picture in MMA,can somebody give me some guidance ,cause my codes take a long time though,it cannnot give me an answer

```
ClearAll;
nco=1.4681;
ncl=1.4628;
rco=4.2*10^3;
wl=Range[1000,2000,5]
$RecursionLimit=Infinity;
u=2*Pi*rco*(nco^2-ncoeff^2)^(1/2)/wl;
w=2*Pi*rco*(ncoeff^2-ncl^2)^(1/2)/wl;
ncoeff=NSolve[u*BesselJ[0,u]/BesselJ[1,u]-w*BesselK[1,w]/BesselK[0,w]==0,ncoeff]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nco = 1.4681 // Rationalize;
ncl = 1.4628 // Rationalize;
rco = 4.2*10^3 // Rationalize;

u = 2*Pi*rco*(nco^2 - ncoeff^2)^(1/2)/wl;

w = 2*Pi*rco*(ncoeff^2 - ncl^2)^(1/2)/wl;

f[ncoeff_, wl_] = 
  u*BesselJ[0, u]/BesselJ[1, u] - w*BesselK[1, w]/BesselK[0, w] // Simplify;
```

The function has even symmetry in `ncoeff`

```
f[-ncoeff, wl] == f[ncoeff, wl]

(* True *)
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 LogLinearPlot[f[ncoeff, wl], {ncoeff, 0, 10000}, WorkingPrecision -> 100,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {-5*^-4, 6*^-5}],
 {{wl, 1500}, 1000, 2000, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

For `ncoeff > 0` the function is monotonically increasing and only asymptotically approaches zero.

```
NMaximize[{f[ncoeff, wl], 1000 <= wl <= 2000, ncoeff > 10}, {ncoeff, wl}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 500] // N
```

[image]

Consequently, there are no finite roots for `NSolve` to find.